# query insert image name to database

Tags: php

What is the proper way of using query insert when uploading image name to databse? Here is a short code that is not working.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table_name
    SET images1="' . $_FILES['file1']['name'] . '",
        images2="' . $_FILES['file2']['name'] . '",
        images3="' . $_FILES['file3']['name'] . '",
        images4="' . $_FILES['file4']['name'] . '"'
```

Comment: Query is incorrect it's not insert query

Comment: How can I make this insert into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a UPDATE query:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table_name
    SET images1="' . $_FILES['file1']['name'] . '",
        images2="' . $_FILES['file2']['name'] . '",
        images3="' . $_FILES['file3']['name'] . '",
        images4="' . $_FILES['file4']['name'] . '"';
```

INSERT should be:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table_name (images1, images2, images3, images4) 
    values( "' . $_FILES['file1']['name'] . '",
            "' . $_FILES['file2']['name'] . '",
            "' . $_FILES['file3']['name'] . '",
            "' . $_FILES['file4']['name'] . '"
)';
```

Answer (score 4):

the current structure is update sql but you are using insert command with it.your insert will be something like this:

```
    $query='INSERT INTO table_name (images1,images2,images3,images4) 
        values("'.$_FILES['file1']['name'].'", "'.$_FILES['file2']['name'].'",
 "'.$_FILES['file3']['name'].'", "'.$_FILES['file4']['name'].'")';
```

if you want update then use:

```
    $query='update table_name SET images1="'.$_FILES['file1']['name'].'",
     images2="'.$_FILES['file2']['name'].'", images3="'.$_FILES['file3']['name'].'",
 images4="'.$_FILES['file4']['name'].'"' // add where clause if any
```

Comment: @user7368271 use the first sql. but before that check whether you are getting the values properly.

Answer (score 0):

Insert query is like

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

you are writing update query where we use `column_name=vlaue` 
So your query will be

```
$query='INSERT INTO table_name (images1,images2,images3,images4) 
values("'.$_FILES['file1']['name'].'", "'.$_FILES['file2']['name'].'", "'.$_FILES['file3']['name'].'", "'.$_FILES['file4']['name'].'")';
```